# FLEX Cannot build lex.yy.c

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, flex-lexer

Downloaded [flex-2.5.37.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flex/files/flex-2.5.37.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=heanet&download=)

Unpacked and followed *INSTALL*'s instructions: `./configure` + `make` + `make install`

In a new folder, I've written a file `example.l` containing:

```
%{
int a = 0, b = 0;
%}

%%
\n   ++a; ++b;
.    ++b;

%%
int main()
{
     yylex();
     printf("%d - %d", a, b);
}
```

which is a basic example from their website. Counting lines and characters in a file.

In a terminal, I ran `flex example.l`. It generated `lex.yy.c`

After that: 
- `gcc lex.yy.c -o lexyy`: Throws *undefined symbols for architecture x86_64* 
- `gcc lex.yy.c -lfl`: *ld: library not found for -lfl* 
- `gcc lex.yy.c -ll`: Generates *a.out*, but when I run it against a file, it doesn't work (prints "0 - 0").

It seems that I can't get this damn file to compile. How does it know where to find the necessary libraries? Shouldn't the linking work from here (this current folder)?

It's a bit depressing that I can't get the simplest of examples going.

Comment: What exactly did you do after you got the program to compile? What behavior did it exhibit and what did you try to do? I ask because it is supposed to wait for input from standard input and read until EOF.

Comment: If you ran `./configure` with no arguments, then your `make install` should have installed `libfl.a` and/or `libfl.so` into `/usr/local/lib`. Check for those files there. If they're missing, you need to find out why. If at least one of them is present, then try adding `-L/usr/local/lib` before the `-lfl`

Comment: @ChronoKitsune The executable compiled from the `lex.yy.c` blueprint should be ran with a random file, and then print out the number of lines and number of characters in that file (of course, the random file is generally a text file in my case). `./a.out < lex.yy.c` prints `"14 - 115"` ==> So those are the statistics for the file `lex.yy.c`, but it can be any file.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Aw man.. my `/usr/local/lib` has only one folder (a perl instalment - nothing to do with what I need). Knowing this, when I have to run the `make install` again, how do I remove the current installation? Will `make distclean` do?

Comment: Actually, now that I've noticed the osx tag, I'm not so sure that `/usr/local/lib` is the right location. It would be interesting to see the messages printed to the terminal when you run `make install` (I'm aware it could be a lot). On the other topic, `clean` and `distclean` only work on the build directory; most GNU packages use `make uninstall` as the opposite of `make install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. So it turns out I was missing a parameter named `%option noyywrap`, which goes here:

```
%{
int a = 0, b = 0;
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
\n   ++a; ++b;
.    ++b;
...
```

Apparently this tells FLEX that there's only one source file. So it's not a `gcc` issue, it was a FLEX config problem.

Thank you all for taking the time to read the question. Hope this helps anyone else.